# Dynamic 95th percentile for special value

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

In my work, I need to use the custom 95th percentile for Tableau:

```
if { FIXED [Account],[domain_name]:SUM([finance_value])} >= 6000 AND [domain_name]='anysite_com'
 then 'more'
else 'less'
END
```

Where:

1. domain_name - site_domain ('anysite_com', 'anysite_by', 'anysite_in'....
2. Account - some user_id (111111111,424522424...)
3. finance_value - some finance value (sum_paid_for_subscribe or other)

But I have trouble: this part of code ***SUM([finance_value])} >= 6000*** is static, but i need a dynamic value for this because many of my dashboards are updated every day, and finance metrics are changing too.
Maybe who knows, how to do this?

Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite tell from your question which of the following you are looking for so here are two options:

**Option 1: Use a parameter**: If you simply want to change the "6000" in your calculation on the fly then you can change your calculation to use a parameter. Simply [create](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_create.htm#create-a-parameter) a new integer (or float if you want decimals) parameter and change your calculation to be  SUM([finance_value])} >= [Your Parameter]. Make sure to show your parameter so you can easily change its value.

**Option 2: Use an extension**: If you need the numbers to be different based on each account or domain then you can use the [Quick What If](https://exchange.tableau.com/products/277) extension. Here you can select either domain or account or even create a combined field with both and use it to change the number for each one individually. (Disclaimer: I built this extension when I worked at Tableau but I no longer work there)